# Security access to a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database and table dbo.Test_Table, with list of Users under Security -> Users. those users have access to all the tables in my database.

I would like to know how do I assign certain users to specific tables (e.g dbo.Test_Table) within the database, that only those Users can view those tables within my database.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008 you can control user access to a table and fields also.All tables and fields are available in the security system, and access can be set up individually for each user group working within a company or domain without affecting other user groups. Table and field access is configured when you set security keys (Administration > Setup > Security > **User group permissions** on the Permissions tab).
For more information visit following link in Microsoft site:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa834466(v=ax.50).aspx